# Prisma, MongoDB many to many relation delete request

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma, endpoint

I have this many to many relation for my two collections:

```
model Product {
  id          String      @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  categories  Category[]  @relation(fields: [categoryIds], references: [id])
  categoryIds String[]    @db.ObjectId
  name        String      @unique
  description String
  count       Int
  image       String
  path        String
  price       Float
  orders      OrderItem[]
}

model Category {
  id         String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title      String    @unique
  products   Product[] @relation(fields: [productIds], references: [id])
  productIds String[]  @db.ObjectId
}
```

When I delete Product, it disappears from the products array in Category as expected. However the productId stays in the Category productIds array. I don't know how to update this array from delete Product request.

This is my current delete product service function:

```
async remove(id: string) {
        return await this.prismaService.product.delete({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried to access category within the remove function, filter categories based on the product id and update the productIds array, but this didn't work. I also tried to create special function in Category service file that would deal with this but I am not able to access this function.